# How to ignore import statement in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, react-typescript

log.ts has the following code

```
import {LOG} from './log'

LOG.e("tag","error");
LOG.f("tag","error");
LOG.d("tag","error");
```

I want the IntelliSense support for the TS file but don't want the consequences of import on generated javascript.

I simply want the following in my Javascript file (log.js)

```
    LOG.e("tag","error");
    LOG.f("tag","error");
    LOG.d("tag","error");
```

Comment: You can't use something that you are not importing.

Comment: I want IntelliSense and static error check but the require statement that generated due to the import statements. I have a huge project and I am not able how to tickle node modules

Answer (score 0):

`log.ts` file must contain only declarations.

```
declare class LOG {
  public static e(a: string, b: string): void;
  public static f(a: string, b: string): void;
  public static d(a: string, b: string): void;
}
```

If you want to use an imported class, and it should not be included in the generated javascript, then you need to declare it using `declare`.

This class is not functional javascript code, but only declares the type of the class and its methods. When generating javascript, this class will not be included in the build.

But to execute such javascript, `LOG` must already be declared in the global environment.

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwDIHkDi8DeAUPPAA4CuARhAJZjzIAuUDt8IAFFAFz0MzUA7AOYAaeBR6N+wgJQ8AbgHtqwANxFSlGnUbNWAM06S+g0eOPShc+EpXri5Kq10s6wI70tiJn09dtqBAC+BARY2AB0HABETELRItEgMDCKMNEy6uERhrFQ8YnJqemZYTgR7nkFSSlpGepAA)...

Comment: could you please exaggerate your answer, I didn't get you.

Comment: @Mehtab ok, added playground example

Comment: Okay, I get it, now I have log.ts and log.d.ts in place. so could you tell me how to import from declaration file log.d.ts file in my other file? I search it on internet and secondly I have a short of time so kindly help me because I don't wanna dig down into the documentation just for simple importing.

Comment: I have the LOG in the global environment

Comment: @Mehtab You can define declaration in plain .ts file.